# Calculate the integral $\int_{\gamma}\omega$ on the curve

Tags: integration, curves, plane-curves

Calculate the integral $\int_{\gamma}\omega$ on the curve $\gamma(t)=(t\cos(2\pi t), t\sin(2\pi t), t^2)$, $t\in[0,1]$ that is contained in the paraboloid S such that:

$S=$ {$(x,y,z)$ | $z=x^2 + y^2$}

$\omega = ydx+xdy+(x^2 +y^2)dz$

The solution is:
$$t=0(start), t=1 (end) => \gamma(0)=(0,0,0), \gamma(1)=(1,0,1)$$
$$\int_{\gamma}\omega = f(end)-f(start)$$
$f(x,y,z)$ such that:$$\omega = f_1dx_1+f_2dx_2+f_3dx_3$$ $$=> f=xy+\frac{z^2}{2}$$ $$=> \int_\gamma \omega = \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Hint : you are not integrating a scalar function along $\gamma$. It is the scalar product of a vector field with the tangent vector.

Comment: @KurtG. what do you mean? What should I do?

Comment: Study [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Line_integral_of_a_vector_field).

Comment: @KurtG. is the $\omega(\gamma(t))$ I got is correct? or am I missing something?

Comment: No it's not. $\omega$ isn't a scalar function. It is a $1$-form, in other words, the dual of a vector field. Excuse me Sir or Madam. MSE comments are not the place to teach the absolute basics. What in the Wikipedia link was not clear ?

Comment: @KurtG. The op clearly is not familiar with line integrals . So we cannot expect him to be familiar with differential forms. Moreover I think it is the "dx"'s that are confusing the op. I understand what you are trying to say , but we can be a little more kind in trying to resolve the issue. Although the wiki link you provided contains all that is required to solve this question , I think the op lacks a proper reference. A beginners book on vector calculus would suffice .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think instead of going into notions of $1$-forms and stuff associated with differential geometry, it is better to define the line integral for the op using vector calculus and multivariable calculus because I think the op is confused by the "$dx,dy,dz$" .(For reference see Murray R Spiegel Vector Analysis of the Schaums Outline series). [Here's a link](http://www.uop.edu.pk/ocontents/Vector%20Analysis%20Schaum.pdf).

Given a vector valued function
$\vec{f}:\mathbb{R}^{3}\to\mathbb{R}^{3}$ such that

$\vec{f}(x,y,z)=f_{1}\hat{i}+f_{2}\hat{j}+f_{3}\hat{k}$

$f_{1},f_{2},f_{3}$ are scalar functions of $(x,y,z)$

The line integral over a curve $\gamma$ of the function is defined as:-

$$\int_{\gamma}\vec{f}\cdot d\vec{r}=\int_{\gamma}(f_{1}\,dx+f_{2}\,dy+f_{3}\,dz)$$

Define:-
$\omega=y\hat{i}+x\hat{j}+(x^{2}+y^{2})\hat{k}$

Now on the curve $\gamma$ given, $x=t\cos(2\pi t)$ so $dx=\cos(2\pi t)-2\pi t\sin(2\pi t)$
Do the same for $dy$ and $dz$. Essentially since the curve is parametrized by $t$ we are just converting the integral into an integral over the parameter $t$.
Then

$$\int_{\gamma}\omega\cdot \vec{dr} = \int_{0}^{1} \Big(t\sin(2\pi t) d(t\cos(2\pi t))+t\cos(2\pi t)d(t\sin(2\pi t))+t^2d(t^{2}) \Big)$$

This is the general method for evaluating Line integrals. (Also note that the curve lies "on" the paraboloid and not "in"), i.e.  it lies on the surface. In terms of Physics, think of $\omega$ as a Force and you are calculating the work done by the force in moving a particle of unit mass along the curve $\gamma$ .