# How to evaluate $\int^{}_{c} y dx + z dy + x dz$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

How to calculate $$\int^{}_{c} y dx + z dy + x dz$$
Where C consists of the segment $C_{1}$ joining $(2,0,0)$ to $(3,4,5)$ followed by the vertical line segment C2 from $(3,4,5)$ to $(3,4,0)$

I'm thinking of parameterizing C1, starting parameterization $(2,0,0)$ to $(3,4,5)$:
Let $$A(2,0,0)$$ and$$B 
(3,4,5)$$
Parameterization formula: $$(x,y,z)=B.t+(1-t).A$$
$$(x,y,z)=(3,4,5).t+(1-t).(2,0,0)$$
$$(x,y,z)=(3t,4t,5t)+(2-2t,0,0)$$
$$(x,y,z)=(2+t,4t,5t)$$

So our vector$$r(t)=(2+t)\hat{i}+(4t)\hat{j}+(5t)\hat{k}$$
$$r'(t)=(1,4,5)$$
$$ |r'(t) |=\sqrt{1^{2}+4^{2}+5^{2}}=\sqrt{42}$$
I don't know how to continue.the function $f(x,y,z)$ is $x+y+z$? then I would apply Line integral

Comment: Do you know how to parameterize a line segment? Still too early for Green's theorem?

Comment: I know how to parameterize the segment, but I haven't learned green's theorem yet, line integral only

Comment: @user170231 You’d better review Green’s Theorem.

Comment: If you know how to parametrize the line then what is the problem you are facing while solving the question?. Also add in your efforts in the question

Comment: @TedShifrin Why is that? We can close $C$ and integrate over a triangle instead, then subtract a line integral.

Comment: This is a ridiculous amount of work, especially since your triangle is in an unusual plane. Green's Theorem is ordinarily stated just for the coordinate plane. So you're really asking the OP to apply Stokes's Theorem, and do far more work than the direct method entails.

Comment: My mistake, completely blanked on the fact that this is in 3D, not 2.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron added where i left off

Comment: Also [Mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) . Please read it over.

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Line_integral_of_a_vector_field)

For a general reference to vector calculus look at Murray Spiegel Vector Analysis .

Also you can look at my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4417885/calculate-the-integral-int-gamma-omega-on-the-curve/4418569#4418569) .

Take the function $f(x,y,z)=y\hat{i}+z\hat{j}+x\hat{k}$ and $\vec{dr}=dx\hat{i}+dy\hat{j}+dz\hat{k}$.

For $C_{1}$ the parametrization is $(2+t,4t,5t)$

Then $dx=d(2+t)$ , $dy=d(4t)$ , $dz=d(5t)$.

So $$\int_{C_{1}}f\cdot \vec{dr}=\int_{0}^{1}\Big((4t)d(2+t)+ 5t\cdot(d(4t))+(2+t)d(5t)\,\Big)dt$$

Do the same for $C_{2}$ and add them up to get the answer.

Comment: When I finish doing C2, can I change the question for you to see?

Comment: Yeah ofc. Just mention by an @ and I will be notified

Answer (score 0):

You can parameterize $C_1$ by $x(t) = 2+t, y(t) = 4t, z(t) = 5t$ with $0 \le t \le 1$. By definition the line integral on $C_1$ is
$$\int_{C_1} y \, dx + z \, dy + x \, dz = \int_0^1 y(t) x'(t) + z(t) y'(t)+ x(t) z'(t) \, dt = \int_0^1 4t + 20t + 5(2+t) \, dt$$
which you should have no trouble evaluating. Find a similar parameterization for $C_2$ to evaluate
$$\int_{C_2} y \, dx + z \, dy + x \, dz$$ and add these together to find the full line integral.